# Can all aberrations be fully removed by a lens system in theory?

Tags: optics, lenses

I recently came across an interesting argument (in Mack's "Fundamental Principles of Optical Lithography", beginning of Chapter 3): By adding more and more lenses to an imaging system, more and more aberrations can be removed, since with each lens you have another degree of freedom to remove aberrations. To remove all aberrations fully, however, would take an infinite number of lenses, so this cannot be achieved.

I may be reading too much into the couple of paragraphs in the book that talk about this, but I was wondering if this is just meant to be a hand-wavy argument, or does it come from some kind of concrete theorem in optics? I.e., is there a theorem that states something like, "To reduce $n$ aberrations to $0$, a minimum of $n$ lenses are required."?

If so, I would be very interested if anyone could point me toward it and/or provide an explanation.

(Note: Unless the assumption of even the smallest manufacturing defect is a premise necessary to understand this fully, I am not very interested here in lens defects that come from manufacturing / processing issues or other engineering difficulties. I am interested in the limits of aberration removal under the most ideal circumstances, i.e., under the assumption that glass (or whatever other material) is perfectly homogeneous, and can be shaped as desired to perfect precision.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can't be such a theorem in general, because you could always exactly deform a lens (like in adaptive optics) to correct the entire wavefront in one single optical component. This is often done with a mirror (see image below), and can be done with a lens as well.

However, if you restrict yourself to a certain class of lenses, then you can form such a theorem, but the result would depend on precisely what kinds of lenses you choose to work with.

[image: Correcting an image with aberrations with a deformable mirror]
Image from: [From Light: Science & Applications volume 3, page e165 (2014)](https://www.nature.com/articles/lsa201446)